# Is Hyouge Mono historically accurate?

Tags: hyouge-mono

The anime and manga, Hyouge Mono, is set in the Sengoku era and follows tea related items. I can see that in general the events of the era seem to be more or less accurate, and all the wacky outfits probably aren't accurate (or are they?), but I'm wondering about the tea related aspect of the series.

Did the warlords of the time (especially Oda Nobunaga) have tea masters and treasure master crafted tea-ware in any way like they're portrayed in Hyouge Mono? Are any of the crafted items, at least the ones with proper names, real items from the period?

Comment: Most [iconic figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oda_Nobunaga) in Japanese history seems to be historically accurate, except for Sasuke (though he seems to be based on [Furuta Oribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furuta_Shigenari)), Senno, and many of the supporting cast. The use of [firearms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firearms_of_Japan) and [Atakebune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atakebune) warships seem to be accurate portrayals of the [Sengoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sengoku_period) period.

Answer (score 1):

All characters on the show are based on historical figures. Furuta Sasuke is in fact Furuta Oribe but he will only change his name later in life.
Same goes for Sen no Soeki who will become famous under the name of Sen no Rikyu.

Comment: You may want to improve your answer by providing links to some things you claim to be true. See @кяαzєя 's comment as an example of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tea bowls and items are real names.
There are records of those. As you can see in Hyouge mono, there was an tea economy rose by tea masters and samurai lords.

Lord Hisahide Matsunaga who blew up with hiragumo kettle in manga and anime, in fact blew up with hiragumo in the top of the castle.
Nobunaga really wanted it, too.
There isn't a record of that Oribe took the broken lid of the kettle though.
So the events appear in the manga or anime are accurate but some scenes Oribe with other samurai lords (especially enemy ones) are more fictional.
Clothes are very exaggerated but Nobunaga really liked western clothes (from Portugal).
In my opinion the author does it deliberately because exaggeration is more suited to Oribe's aesthetic sense.
Later his name remains in style of tea bowls as Oribe ware.

Comment: While you attempt to answer the question, you provide no sources. You say there are records of the items, yet you provide none. You say the events are accurate, maybe providing some references of examples to specific events would be useful as an answer.